# Android LayoutParams Problem - View always up top

Tags: android, cocos2d-android, mobclix

I'm trying to put a mobclix ad banner in a cocos2D game.  I have the ad banner showing up on top of the openGL view.  However, I can not figure out how to place it at the bottom of the screen which is what we want.  The example from mobclix shows the use of a LinearLayout with gravity set to bottom.  I tried this in the GameActivity which is the main activity on startup:

```
    adview_banner = new MobclixMMABannerXLAdView(this);
    adview_banner.addMobclixAdViewListener(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

    this.addContentView(adview_banner, params);

    adview_banner.bringToFront();
    adview_banner.getAd();
    adview_banner.setRefreshTime(30000);
```

No matter what I do here the banner always shows up on the top of the screen.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you eleborate whr you add this view in xml or dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

OK!  I think I finally have it!  Those layouts are tricky at first programmatically but they do match up with what the example had in the xml.  I just needed to embed the banner in a layout object and send it to the bottom of that layout.

In the main Activity:

```
    @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    adview_banner = new MobclixMMABannerXLAdView(this);
    adview_banner.addMobclixAdViewListener(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams childParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(320, 50);
    childParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    layout.addView(adview_banner, childParams);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(layout, params);

    //adview_banner.bringToFront();
    adview_banner.getAd();
    adview_banner.setRefreshTime(30000);
}
```

Now the only issue is that I get a "can't get the viewWidth after the first layout error" on the Logcat from "webcore".  And the ad banner displays "An error has occurred.  Click here for more details."

I think I'll consult the Mobclix support team on that one.

Comment: What does the Mobclix team respond on your error??Are you able to display ads now?

Answer (score -2):

Use Absolute Layout.

```
    android:layout_width="40px"
    android:layout_marginRight="5px"
    android:layout_height="40px"
```

etc

Linear Layouts can only set gravities to each individual child.

Was it useful?

Comment: I have to programmatically add the view because I had no luck using XML since the main Activity view is an OpenGL view.  It didn't seem like there was a way to overlay an XML defined view on the GL view.  The code above is in onStart() in the initial Activity.  I have also tried putting the code in other places such as onEnter() above and below the GL view creation.  I have also tried defining it in xml but get a force close because I can't load the view into the GL view activity.  I can post more code when I get home today and also try the suggested AbsoluteLayout.  I haven't tried that yet.